# how to maintain consistent cell height in a div based table

Tags: css

I have a div and css responsive table but the cell height is inconsistent i.e. if one cell in a row is two lines in height the row becomes mangled (as can be seen in the photo).
[image]

this is my code:

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 10% auto 0;
  border-collapse: separate;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.table_row {
  display: table-row;
}

.theader {
  display: table-row;
}

.table_header {
  display: table-cell;
  border-bottom: #ccc 1px solid;
  border-top: #ccc 1px solid;
  background: #bdbdbd;
  color: #e5e5e5;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.table_header:first-child {
  border-left: #ccc 1px solid;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
}

.table_header:last-child {
  border-right: #ccc 1px solid;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

.table_small {
  display: table-cell;
}

.table_row>.table_small>.table_cell:nth-child(odd) {
  display: none;
  background: #bdbdbd;
  color: #e5e5e5;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.table_row>.table_small>.table_cell {
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  color: #5b5b5b;
  border-bottom: #ccc 1px solid;
}

.table_row>.table_small:first-child>.table_cell {
  border-left: #ccc 1px solid;
}

.table_row>.table_small:last-child>.table_cell {
  border-right: #ccc 1px solid;
}

.table_row:last-child>.table_small:last-child>.table_cell:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

.table_row:last-child>.table_small:first-child>.table_cell:last-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}

.table_row:nth-child(2n+3) {
  background: #e9e9e9;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .table {
    width: 90%
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  .table {
    display: block;
  }
  .table_row:nth-child(2n+3) {
    background: none;
  }
  .theader {
    display: none;
  }
  .table_row>.table_small>.table_cell:nth-child(odd) {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;
  }
  .table_cell {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;
  }
  .table_row {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: separate;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    margin: 5% auto 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .table_small {
    display: table-row;
  }
  .table_row>.table_small:first-child>.table_cell:last-child {
    border-left: none;
  }
  .table_row>.table_small>.table_cell:first-child {
    border-left: #ccc 1px solid;
  }
  .table_row>.table_small:first-child>.table_cell:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top: #ccc 1px solid;
  }
  .table_row>.table_small:first-child>.table_cell:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-top: #ccc 1px solid;
  }
  .table_row>.table_small:last-child>.table_cell:first-child {
    border-right: none;
  }
  .table_row>.table_small>.table_cell:last-child {
    border-right: #ccc 1px solid;
  }
  .table_row>.table_small:last-child>.table_cell:first-child {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  }
  .table_row>.table_small:last-child>.table_cell:last-child {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="table" id="results">
  <div class='theader'>
    <div class='table_header'>Header One</div>
    <div class='table_header'>Header Two</div>
    <div class='table_header'>Header Three</div>
    <div class='table_header'>Header Four</div>
  </div>
  <div class='table_row'>
    <div class='table_small'>
      <div class='table_cell'>Header One</div>
      <div class='table_cell'>-1.2726 -1.2726
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='table_small'>
      <div class='table_cell'>Header Two</div>
      <div class='table_cell'>0.1311</div>
    </div>
    <div class='table_small'>
      <div class='table_cell'>Header Three</div>
      <div class='table_cell'>-0.4782</div>
    </div>
    <div class='table_small'>
      <div class='table_cell'>Header Four</div>
      <div class='table_cell'>-0.9919<br>-1.2726</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='table_row'>
    <div class='table_small'>
      <div class='table_cell'>Header One</div>
      <div class='table_cell'>-0.89</div>
    </div>
    <div class='table_small'>
      <div class='table_cell'>Header Two</div>
      <div class='table_cell'>0.7986</div>
    </div>
    <div class='table_small'>
      <div class='table_cell'>Header Three</div>
      <div class='table_cell'>0.876</div>
    </div>
    <div class='table_small'>
      <div class='table_cell'>Header Four</div>
      <div class='table_cell'>0.498</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='table_row'>
    <div class='table_small'>
      <div class='table_cell'>Header One</div>
      <div class='table_cell'>-1.1669</div>
    </div>
    <div class='table_small'>
      <div class='table_cell'>Header Two</div>
      <div class='table_cell'>0.4949<br>-1.2726</div>
    </div>
    <div class='table_small'>
      <div class='table_cell'>Header Three</div>
      <div class='table_cell'>-0.7113</div>
    </div>
    <div class='table_small'>
      <div class='table_cell'>Header Four</div>
      <div class='table_cell'>0.434</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='table_row'>
    <div class='table_small'>
      <div class='table_cell'>Header One</div>
      <div class='table_cell'>0.1996</div>
    </div>
    <div class='table_small'>
      <div class='table_cell'>Header Two</div>
      <div class='table_cell'>-0.7693</div>
    </div>
    <div class='table_small'>
      <div class='table_cell'>Header Three</div>
      <div class='table_cell'>1.974</div>
    </div>
    <div class='table_small'>
      <div class='table_cell'>Header Four</div>
      <div class='table_cell'>-0.959</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='table_row'>
    <div class='table_small'>
      <div class='table_cell'>Header One</div>
      <div class='table_cell'>-1.5998</div>
    </div>
    <div class='table_small'>
      <div class='table_cell'>Header Two</div>
      <div class='table_cell'>-0.1149</div>
    </div>
    <div class='table_small'>
      <div class='table_cell'>Header Three</div>
      <div class='table_cell'>1.3888</div>
    </div>
    <div class='table_small'>
      <div class='table_cell'>Header Four</div>
      <div class='table_cell'>-0.0689</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

how to fix up the code so the height of all the cells will remain consistent and all cells will be in the same height as the highest cell in the row?

fix up the code so the height of all the cells will remain consistent and all cells will be in the same height as the highest cell in the row.

Comment: Why are you not just using a table?

Comment: I'm just looking to learn how to do that with a div and not a table